# NPM and Yarn lock files

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

Is there some method for `npm` to consume the `yarn.lock` file ? I am working on a project that uses the `NpmInstallWebpackplugin` and it's docs indicate that this plugin install modules on the fly via `npm` but I am using `yarn`, is there a way I might get this thing to work.

Answer (score 1):

`NpmInstallWebpackPlugin` has been last released 4 years ago (version 4.0.5 from August 17, 2017). There is a [pull request](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/npm-install-webpack-plugin/pull/115) adding yarn support merged in 2018, but it's not released to NPM.

If possible, you could eventually switch to [yarn-add-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn-add-webpack-plugin).

Comment: yeah it's not reflected at npmjs, although thanks for the alternative plugin @Rafael

Answer (score 0):

Seem to be a yarn implementation :
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/npm-install-webpack-plugin/blob/master/src/installer.js#L179

Could try to use it, fix problems and MR the repo